# Swagger integration into Play framework Java with imported routes in routes file

Tags: java, playframework, routes, gulp, swagger

I am trying to integrate swagger into my play 2.4 project with https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-play/tree/master/play-2.4/swagger-play2.

In my conf/routes file I have an imported routes syntax like this.

-> / gulp.Routes

When I add this syntax and start the server. There is a swagger error thrown saying

```
"play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is         not     hierarchical
at play.modules.swagger.SwaggerPluginImpl.(SwaggerPlugin.scala:33)
while locating play.modules.swagger.SwaggerPluginImpl
at play.modules.swagger.SwaggerModule.bindings(SwaggerModule.scala:11): " etc.
```

I think the problem arises because swagger cannot parse the syntax for imported routes.

Anyone knows a fix/work-around ?